# Where can I found add to cart button code on Spree github page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cart, spree

Can someone direct me which code in Spree refers to specifically Add To Cart button(in views and controller)?

Answer (score 2):

Cart routes (like adding an item or viewing your current cart) points to the Orders controller.

[routes.rb](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/e1b48ddd90706f68bd75b2393b66a23c7c124498/frontend/config/routes.rb#L19)

```
get '/cart', to: 'orders#edit', as: :cart
patch '/cart', to: 'orders#update', as: :update_cart
put '/cart/empty', to: 'orders#empty', as: :empty_cart
```

Here are [controller](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/e1b48ddd90706f68bd75b2393b66a23c7c124498/frontend/app/controllers/spree/orders_controller.rb) and [views](https://github.com/spree/spree/tree/e1b48ddd90706f68bd75b2393b66a23c7c124498/frontend/app/views/spree/orders)